# How to show a video component in blazor hybrid?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-hybrid

this code works just fine in blazor server, but it is not working in blazor hybrid, whitch is the correct way to show video in an android app with blazor Hybrid?  I need assistance in creating a video component within my application.

```
<BlazoredVideo  class="w-100" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" style="max-width:800px;">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</BlazoredVideo>
```

[it just show this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrXnR.png)